# how to toggle or change HTML class name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to change the color of the navigation bar when the theme change button is clicked.

This is HTML code

```
<header class="header">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
  </a>
  <nav class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-list">
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#introduction">Intro</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#portfolio">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#contact">Hello</a>
      </li>
      <!-- <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">section4</a></li> -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Javascript code

```
const themeChange = () => { 
   const navElements = document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav-link");
    // console.log("nav: " + navElements.length);
    for (let i = 0; i <= navElements.length; i++) {
      console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav-link")[i]);
      document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav-link")[i].className =
        "main-nav-link-summer";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change the class name from "main-nav-link" to "main-nav-link-summer" so the color for active, hover can be changed. But weirdly, only the first and third tags are changed and the second remains the same. The length of the "navElements" variable is 3.

CSS code

```
.main-nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 4.8rem;
  align-items: center;
  /* padding-right: 5rem; */
  /* font-size: x-large; */
}

.main-nav-link,
.main-nav-link-summer {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  /* font size 1.8 */
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.main-nav-link-summer:hover,
.main-nav-link-summer:active {
  color: #1d4116;
}

.main-nav-link:hover,
.main-nav-link:active {
  color: #a63ec5;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.97);
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 0 100.2rem 3.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.sticky .main-nav-link {
  color: #46244c;
}

.sticky .main-nav-link:hover,
.sticky .main-nav-link:active {
  color: #a63ec5;
}
```

Comment: you can achieve that without complicating stuff

Comment: @SteveWalson I'm sure there would be a better way but the problem is that I don't know the better one. Could you please share the better solution?

Comment: let's get it simpler, you wanna change the navigation bar color whenever you click on a nav link right?

Comment: Yes basically. I didn't add theme change button, but there's theme change button separately outside of navigation bar. I don't get why only the second tag remains same when the first and third navigation tag is changed!

Comment: edit the code and show me CSS so i can see what's happening with you

Comment: I just did! I've added all relevant css codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript that's the easiest way, for what you wanna achieve I'm not exactly sure.

```js
const navElements = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav-link");

navElements.forEach((link) => {
  link.classList.add("main-nav-link-summer");
});
```

```css
.main-nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 4.8rem;
  align-items: center;
  /* padding-right: 5rem; */
  /* font-size: x-large; */
}

.main-nav-link,
.main-nav-link-summer {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  /* font size 1.8 */
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.main-nav-link-summer:hover,
.main-nav-link-summer:active {
  color: #1d4116;
}

.main-nav-link:hover,
.main-nav-link:active {
  color: #a63ec5;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.97);
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 0 100.2rem 3.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.sticky .main-nav-link {
  color: #46244c;
}

.sticky .main-nav-link:hover,
.sticky .main-nav-link:active {
  color: #a63ec5;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
  </a>
  <nav class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-list">
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#introduction">Intro</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#portfolio">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#contact">Hello</a>
      </li>
      <!-- <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">section4</a></li> -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: ForEach method looks way cleaner than for loop. Thank you. I don't know what happened but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different approach all together. Going through and doing mass class name changes is really sub-optimal for dev and maintenance. Perhaps consider an approach like the example below instead as a simple proof of concept using separated css var themes so as you build you don't think about such things and can handle a design system much more flexibly without piling on lots of unnecessary extra code. Cheers.

```js
const htmlEl = document.documentElement;

// set a detault or read their saved selection from localstorage or whatever.
htmlEl.dataset.theme = 'default';
      
// set the new selectiong when made.
toggleTheme = (theme) => htmlEl.dataset.theme = theme;
```

```css
html[data-theme="default"] {
  --body-bg: #f1f1f1;
  --body-color: #000;
  --btn-color: #212121;
  --btn-bg: #fff;
  --btn-hover-color: #a63ec5;
  --btn-hover-bg: #ddd;
}

html[data-theme="summer"] {
  --body-bg: lightblue;
  --body-color: #000;
  --btn-color: darkgreen;
  --btn-bg: lightyellow;
  --btn-hover-color: #1d4116;
  --btn-hover-bg: #f1f1f1;
}

html[data-theme="winter"] {
  --body-bg: #333;
  --body-color: #fff;
  --btn-color: #f1f1f1;
  --btn-bg: #212121;
  --btn-hover-color: lightblue; 
  --btn-hover-bg: #555;
}

html {
  color: var(--body-color);
  background-color: var(--body-bg);
}

.main-nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* padding-right: 5rem; */
  /* font-size: x-large; */
}

.main-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--btn-color);
  background-color: var(--btn-bg);
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  /* font size 1.8 */
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.main-nav-list li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

.main-nav-link:hover,
.main-nav-link:active {
  color: var(--btn-hover-color);
  background-color: var(--btn-hover-bg);
}
```

```html
<br>
<strong>Choose your theme:</strong>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="toggleTheme(this.value)">
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="summer">Summer</option>
  <option value="winter">Winter</option>
</select>

<br><hr><br>

<header class="header">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
  </a>
  <nav class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-list">
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#introduction">Intro</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#portfolio">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#contact">Hello</a>
      </li>
      <!-- <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">section4</a></li> -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: wow I ddn't think of toggle method! Thank you for the advice Chris!